# 2 classes trying to access each others methods, can't solve dependancies

Tags: c++, dependencies

I am learning c++ and writing a game. it was going more or less okey. but the bigger it gets the more trouble i get from dependencies.
How can i fix this kind of dependency?

```
class myClass_2;

    class myClass_1 {
        private:
            myClass_2 * myclass2;
        public:
            myClass_1() {}
            void setUp(myClass_2 &myclass) {
                myclass2 = &myclass;
            }
            void doSomething_1(){
                myclass2->doSomething_2();
            }
    };

    class myClass_2 {
        private:
            myClass_1 * myclass1;
        public:
            myClass_2() {}
            void setUp(myClass_1 &myclass) {
                        myclass1 = &myclass;
                    }
            void doSomething_2() {
                myclass1->doSomething_1();
            }
    };

    int main () {
        myClass_1 class_1;
        myClass_2 class_2;
        class_1.setUp(class_2);
        class_2.setUp(class_1);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you're not really doing anything like this in real code? I mean you will end up with a SO if you call `doSomething_1|2` If you have a circular dependency, I suggest you look at your design...

Comment: i am. how else can i make major classes that work with different part of programm to interact between theme selfs. I have MapGrid class. that manages map and everything with it. it stores id numbers of units in each map square. Then i have unitfactory that controls everything that has to do with units. units have id. when i make a new unit i need to pass ID,x,y coordinates to mapGrid so it can update map. when i say kill everything in x,y coordinates in MapGrid i need to tell UnitFactory to kill units with those ID that are in x, y location

Comment: why does something that is a "factory" need to keep state about something it has created? Surely once the factory has created the item, it's up to something else to manage the lifetime of that instance? So from your comment, what I gather is that the factory creates the unit, and the mapgrid should manage the life time of it, why does one need to know (or care) about the other?

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the class definition in a header file (with `.h` extension) and a source file (`.cpp` or `.cc` file). And then use `#include` to include the header file to solve these types of problems. See this link for a more detailed explanation: [Header files in C++](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your classes in header files, and define member functions in cpp files.

```
//class1.h
class myClass_2;
class myClass_1 {
    private:
        myClass_2 * myclass2;
    public:
        myClass_1();
        void setUp(myClass_2 &myclass);
        void doSomething_1();
};


//class1.cpp
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"

myClass_1::myClass_1() {
}

void myClass_1::setUp(myClass_2 &myclass) {
    myclass2 = &myclass;
}

void myClass_1::doSomething_1() {
    myclass2->doSomething_2();
}
```

Then do the same for `myClass_2`. You don't need myClass_2's *member function* definition in order to call the member functions, you only need the *class* definition found in `class2.h`

Comment: like this i will have lots of .cpp files. how will i make compiler understand in what order should it put them together? since each seperate file will have only header

Comment: The order of compilation doesn't matter. The header files basically say "a class exists and it looks like this", the cpp files provide the actual code for these classes. The linker handles the rest.

Comment: so i can compile like this basically. "g++ main.cpp something.cpp /something/something.cpp -o myProgram". if its that way wont that string get huge and hard to manage?

Comment: `g++ -Wall -c -o main.o main.cpp` compiles one file. Compile all of them like that, then link with `g++ -o myapp main.o file1.o file2.o`. Also consider learning how to write a Makefile

Answer (score 1):

**Move the function bodies outside the class bodies.**

```
class myClass_2;

class myClass_1 {
    private:
        myClass_2 * myclass2;
    public:
        myClass_1() {}
        void setUp(myClass_2 &myclass);
        void doSomething_1();
};

class myClass_2 {
    private:
        myClass_1 * myclass1;
    public:
        myClass_2() {}
        void setUp(myClass_1 &myclass);
        void doSomething_2();
};

void myClass_1::setUp(myClass_2 &myclass) {
    myclass2 = &myclass;
}
void myClass_1::doSomething_1(){
    myclass2->doSomething_2();
}

void myClass_2::setUp(myClass_1 &myclass) {
    myclass1 = &myclass;
}
void myClass_2::doSomething_2() {
    myclass1->doSomething_1();
}

int main () {
    myClass_1 class_1;
    myClass_2 class_2;
    class_1.setUp(class_2);
    class_2.setUp(class_1);
    return 1;
}
```

In professional object-oriented programming class function declarations and definitions are often kept in separate *.h and *.cpp files. Then the *.h file is included in the main file.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had said what trouble you were getting exactly.

If the trouble is that it can't compile `myClass_1::doSomething1()` because it doesn't know how to call `myclass2->doSomething2()`, the solution is to move the definition of `myClass_1::doSomething1()` below the definition of `myclass_2`:

```
class MyClass_1 {
   ...
   void doSomething_1();  // just declare it here
   ...
}

class My_Class_2 {
   ...
   void doSomething_2();
   ...
}

void MyClass_1::doSomething_1()      // now define it
{
   myclass2->doSomething_2();
}
```